# How do I create a message with interpolated variables and send it with Perl's Mail::Outlook?

Tags: perl, email

I'm using Mail::Outlook to send messages, but when the content of the message is dynamic, for e.g. `Time:$time\nEntry:$e`, it prints this as it is and doesn't substitute the variables. What do I do for that?

Comment: What have you tried so far? Show us your short example script that demonstrates the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I notice that in [the documentation for that module](http://search.cpan.org/dist/Mail-Outlook/lib/Mail/Outlook.pm), the example code always uses single-quoted strings for the body text. Of course, if you use variables in a single-quoted string then the variables won't get expanded. Is that, perhaps, what you're doing?

This is only a guess though. You don't give anywhere near enough detail for us to give any real help.